# How can i associate a library symbol with an existing class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flashdevelop

I am using Flash Develop for compilation ( Not Flash IDE )

Here is a sample code :

```
   [Embed(source = 'assets.swf', symbol = 'app.view.CustomButton')
    var customButton_Class:Class ; 

    var customButton_Instance ;


    customButton_Instance = new customButton_Class();
```

The problem is that this "customButton_Instance" doesnot know anything about app.view.CustomButton ?? ( Actually this means there is no sense in setting the class as app.view.CustomButton in the assets.fla library )

The workaround i am following is :

```
 var customButton:CustomButton = new CustomButton();
customButton.setView( customButton_Instance )
```

But i wanted somehow, the customButton_Instance should automatically associate itself with the customButton class. Any ideas pls ?

Comment: why there is no type in customButton_instance? surely it is at least one of base types, e.g. Sprite, MovieClip. In you r example it looks like you have access to the class referenced as symbol in embed tag, why not, load assets.swf to you app domain and getdefinition for that class?

Comment: Ya.. I too tried to do so ( using app.view.CustomButton), but I get error when using type for customButton_Instance .

Comment: also, i actually wanted to experiment it with "embed" rathar than using "load"

Comment: :) sure, but load doesnt increase the SWF size, embed does:)

Comment: cast it like so - app.view.CustomButton(customButton_Instance) to make it of that type, that's a horrible naming convention might I add.

Comment: casting too results in runtime error.
What i have concluded with this is : EMBED is not a suggested way to use symbols with their class name. It' cannot be done without workarounds.
I think, the only proper way is to use "swc" or dynamic loading via "load"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Embed you lose the symbol's associated class. That's how it works.

Instead, if you're using Flash Pro, choose to Publish a SWC that you can then add to your FlashDevelop project (in FlashDevelop: right-click > Add to Library), and then all the symbols will be visible in code completion like any class and you can just write new app.view.CustomButton() or create a custom class extending it.

Comment: ya.. i noticed that. Embed has this disadvantage.